# Add custom button in footer ngx-quill

Tags: angular, ngx-quill

Is there a way in quill config that i can format the editor as below ? I know i can add a custom toolbar, but is there a way that i can have a button in the footer of the editor ?

[image]

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for that ? i have the same issue too i could not find any clear ressources about this topic :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like that

```
<quill-editor>
  <div quill-editor-toolbar>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-bold" (click)="customFunctionWhenClickButton()" [title]="'Bold'">CUSTOM_BUTTON</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</quill-editor>
```

OR

```
<quill-editor
[modules]="{toolbar:[
    ['custom-button']]
}"
>
</quill-editor>
```